# Should i declare variable each php page?

Tags: php

I wonder about variable declaration in php.. should i declare variable with same variable for each page? example

```
a = '';
b = 0;
```

that variable will have in `page1.php` and `page2.php`, i have to do that? and how about if i have main page such

`main.php` and inside main page i call page1 and page2 using include like

```
main.php
//declare variable
a = '';
b = 0;

echo '<div>include("page1.php")</div>';
echo '<div>include("page2.php")</div>';
```

and in `page1.php` and `page2.php` i declare again same variable in `main.php`... should i do that or just in `main.php` variable will declare?

and seconds

What is the best way to declare variable?

Comment: why would you need to declare variable again in `page1.php`????

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: you can declare `$my_var = 'variable';` in main.php and include that main.php in any other file, now you can access main.php variable via `global $my_var; echo $my_var`;

Comment: @Umair that's why i'm asking.. because i have no idea which one the best way....@Panky Thanks for link..@Touqeer i not like use global..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Never. That's when you use [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data
>   across subsequent accesses. This enables you to build more customized
>   applications and increase the appeal of your web site.

Please refer this [section](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for more information. It will take some time for you to study all of these. If you have any concerns let me know.

Also refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) section as well.

Comment: This doc http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php might be more relevant for this particular question

Comment: If i use session for my variable.. it's safe? have no risk? Thank You

Comment: Nope. That's the industry standard

Comment: @Techie i know about vote... but i'm not done yet... so i'm not give any vote yet..

Answer (score 0):

yes you can declare follow this url

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp